# Apply logging framework with minimum changes in exsisting code

Tags: java

I am using method[print] of a class from jar file. which is used to print logs. Now I have to apply logging framework and project all files uses jar file method for printing logs. Is there any way to do it without doing changes in all files? and I cannot alter jar file classes also. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want some method (print) to do something else without changing it?? If yes, then you could *shadow* it but that's bad design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a `class X` which is in a jar-file that you cannot change, and you have a bunch of

```
X.print("something");
```

all over your code, since that print method is `static`, subclassing `X` in an attempt to override it will not gain you anything (static invocations do not use inheritance; at least in Java). You will need to find all those calls to print and replace them with your logging method of choice.

You can, however, benefit from having a

```
public class Y extends X {
    // ADD constructors calling super(constructorArgs) here
    public static void print(String s) {
        // ADD use of logging framework here
    }
    // ADD all other static methods: call X.methodName(methodArgs);
    // all other dynamic methods: inheritance does it for you
}
```

Then you can replace all `X`s with `Y`s (no need to specifically look for uses of `print`) and things should work fine.

If, instead, you have

```
 X x = new X(/* args here */);
 // ... and lots of these
 x.print("something");
```

then the method is not static, and replacing all calls of the form `new X` with `new Y` would solve the problem. You will have changed a lot of files, but have made very minimal changes in each. All that would change in the `Y` class is that `print` would no longer be `static`.